# Same classes applied to anchor tag IE 11 generates two different background images

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am applying the same classes to two different elements and the what is generated for the background property is different.

I am ending up with 
Button 1 -  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgb(0, 81, 0) 0%, rgb(36, 138, 30) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box

Button 2 - rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgb(36, 138, 30) 0%, rgb(0, 81, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box

I do not understand why I would get two different values generated using the same class.

This is what the background property for the class looks like: 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #248a1e 0%,#005100 100%);

So I am ending up with one button that renders the way that I would expect and the other button looks like the one on this post
[Crossbrowser css gradient in IE10, IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057653/crossbrowser-css-gradient-in-ie10-ie11).

Comment: If we could get a link to the page where this is happening, or a jsfiddle where it's replicated (or even just the actual html and css). Often the issue isn't what you think and there's no way applying the same class will yield different results unless there is something else in play.

Comment: Could you post all of your css and supporting HTML please? It's kind of hard to figure out specifically what may be happening without it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9k6r4okr/

Answer (score 1):

You are using two classes for same button. The last css will get rendered. So The style from "contact-button" get overridden the style of the class "green-button". Use !important for not overridden properties like this.

```
    .green-button {
                text-align: center;
                color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #016d01;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 8px 14px 8px 14px;
                background: #52b152;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #248a1e 0%,#005100 100%) !important;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
```

Comment: If I take off all of the styles and just leave green-button on both anchors, I still get the same effect.

Comment: May be the problem with IE is cache is not being cleared properly and reloaded. Manually clear the cache and try again. I tried in all browser it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried eliminating things to track this down.  The whole time this seemed very odd.  I ended up taking the form elements out of the left gutter as I was eliminating things and the effect went away.  I put all of the form elements back in and took out only the textarea and that was what was causing the problem.  I put the textarea back in and took the class out and it was the class that was applied to the textarea that caused the problem.  I ended up narrowing it down to the font-size property of the class that was causing the glitch.  I ended up putting everything back in and changed my zoom level and the problem went away.  It ended up that there was only one zoom level that was causing the glitch in the button display.  There is definitely some browser display bug going on, so I will checkin my changes and move on.